# Getting user input then implementing it inside a function

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So what I'm doing here is trying to get the user to type in a keyword then using that input to customize a certain search query and then displaying the result.

I would like to attach that input and make it readable inside a function, I've tried making a second function to fetch the input then calling it inside the other function but that doesn't seem to work.

Here is my flask code

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
  keyword = 'KEYWORD'  **I need to make this an input by the user**
  url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q='+ keyword + '&rsz=8')
  response = requests.get(url)
  articles = response.json()
  return render_template('index.html', articles = articles, enumerate=enumerate)


@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def form():
    get_keyword = request.form['keyword']
    return get_keyword

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is my index.html

```
<form method="post" action="/">
<input type="text" name="keyword">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do, and what doesn't work about it? It seems to me like when the user submits the form, they would get forwarded to `/` which would show them the word they entered. The only thing I can think that you're missing is a submit button on the form.

Comment: Why are you trying to handle user input before the form even rendered in the first end point instead of handling the querying in the second (`POST`) handler?

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def hello_world():
  keyword = request.form['keyword']
  url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q='+ keyword + '&rsz=8')
  response = requests.get(url)
  articles = response.json()
  return render_template('index.html', articles = articles, enumerate=enumerate)
```

This should solve your problem. You need to make your first app.route a post request and the inside of this request simply request from here. No need for the extra post function.

This is an example from flask's documentation. It is different but uses the exact same logic and will help you understand what you were doing wrong.
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/views/#tutorial-views